# Remove a column from DataTable based on a where condition using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio, datatable

I have a Dataset  which contains  many dataTable .

The datatables looks like  as follows,

```
   column1  column2 column3  Name
     NA        NA      NA    Ivan
```

Now I want  to remove columns from all datatables in the dataset where row value  is 'NA'.

How can I do this  using Linq if possible?

Comment: You want to remove the columns? Do you mean you want to remove the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you actually want to remove all string-columns of all tables where all values of all rows are `NA`(or `na`). Then this works as expected:

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    List<DataColumn> stringColumns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(string))
        .ToList();
    var columnsAllNotAvailable = stringColumns
        .Where(c => table.AsEnumerable()
            .All(r =>  String.Equals(r.Field<string>(c), "NA", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
    foreach(DataColumn col in columnsAllNotAvailable)
        table.Columns.Remove(col);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove column from collecion via method Remove, and linq can only help you find desired columns.
Find desired columns and then remove them.

```
            var dt = new DataTable();
            List<DataColumn> delete = new List<DataColumn>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    if (row[col]?.ToString() == "NA" && !delete.Contains(col))
                        delete.Add(col);
            foreach (var col in delete)
                dt.Columns.Remove(col);
```

Comment: This removes all columns where there is at least one row with value `NA` in that column. I doubt that this is what OP wants. What if there are thousands of real values but a single `NA` destroys the whole column?! Also doesn't compile below C#6 because of the Null-Conditional operator.